# When I use the `hreflang attribute in Link I get warning

Tags: reactjs, react-router

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import { BrowserRouter as Router, Link } from "react-router-dom";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Router>
        <Link
          hreflang={"en"}
          to={
            "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mmCnQDUSO4I&list=RDmmCnQDUSO4I&start_radio=1"
          }
        >
          {"Dmitri Shostakovich"}
        </Link>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

I'm new to react and react-router. In the console I get this Warning.

> Warning: Invalid DOM property `hreflang`. Did you mean `hrefLang`.

Secondly, the link does not work for me.

Comment: Unrelated side note: you don't have to wrap *everything* into expressions (`{"foo"}`) if it's just a static string. Just do `hrefLang="en"` and `to="https://.."` and `Dmitri` instead of `{"Dmitri"}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because in jsx html attributes are in camelCase.To learn more [read](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#all-supported-html-attributes).change hreflang attribute to hrefLang.`<Link/>` is a router-aware anchor, if you want to link to an external site, use an `<a/>`.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import { BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Router>
        <a
          hrefLang={"en"}
          href={
            "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mmCnQDUSO4I&list=RDmmCnQDUSO4I&start_radio=1"
          }
        >
          {"Dmitri Shostakovich"}
        </a>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Answer (score 1):

React work on `pascalCase`. It is good to use `Link` when you are working with internal navigation. when you are targetting external link you should go with anchor tag i.e `<a>`, also add `target="_blank"` for betterment.

Just change,

```
<Link
      hreflang={"en"}
      to={
        "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mmCnQDUSO4I&list=RDmmCnQDUSO4I&start_radio=1"
      }
    >
      {"Dmitri Shostakovich"}
    </Link>
```

to

```
<a
      target="_blank"
      hrefLang={'en'}
      href={
        'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mmCnQDUSO4I&list=RDmmCnQDUSO4I&start_radio=1'
      }
    >
      {'Dmitri Shostakovich'}
    </a>
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-codesandbox-2gmot?fontsize=14)